# I am looking for Objective C example of how to retrieve emails for MacOS and iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, macos, email

I am looking for Objective C example of how to retrieve emails for MacOS and iOS. I find examples on sending email(Mac's SBSendEmail sample) but not retrieving email. If anybody knows... thank you.

Comment: There is no way to generically "retrieve e-mails." You cannot grab e-mails from either the Mac or the iPhone's built-in mail application, so you have to communicate with a mail server by yourself. Popular mail protocols include IMAP, POP, and Exchange.

Comment: You could try using a framework like MailCore (http://www.mronge.com/code/) or Pantomime, or you may be better of using a C library instead of an Objective-C one.

Comment: In the Xcode IDE, anything that could work is what I am looking for.  I don't know where to look.  You say there is the IMAP POP "C library" ?

Comment: There is no API for this on iOS. You need to implement yourself by learning how to code something from scratch and by reading the RFC for IMAP/POP/SMTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [libEtPan!](http://www.etpan.org/libetpan/index.html). I use it in an app, works quite well. It's a POP3/IMAP/more lib with a C interface.

It's not very well documented, but the code of [etPanKit](http://libetpan.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libetpan/etPanKit/) helped me a lot.

You should read and understand [RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) and [RFC1939](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939) too. A telnet client (and/or openssl) and Wireshark will be helpful too.